# MvvmCross not using shared runtime for mono

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

This is a xamarin android application using MvvmCross.
As soon as I uncheck "Use Shared Runtime" for my Release build, I get an error when trying to run the application.  I think MvvmCross is missing something in it's container, but not sure how to find out what.  Here is the error:

```
Loaded assembly: Mono.Android.Support.v4.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Mono.Android.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Core.dll [External] 
Loaded assembly: MonoDroidConstructors [External]
07-29 15:07:02.034 D/ActivityThread(14030): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
07-29 15:07:02.034 D/ActivityThread(14030): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
07-29 15:07:02.034 D/ActivityThread(14030): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
07-29 14:51:31.771 I/ActivityThread(13053): Pub sdinc.app.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__: mono.MonoRuntimeProvider
07-29 14:51:31.781 W/MonoDroid-Debugger(13053): Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=127.0.0.1:8819,server=y,embedding=1
07-29 14:51:31.942 W/MonoDroid-Debugger(13053): Accepted stdout connection: 43
07-29 14:51:33.443 W/monodroid-gc(13053): GREF GC Threshold: 46800
07-29 14:51:34.985 F/        (13053): * Assertion at /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.7.9-branch/47cd3984/source/mono/mono/metadata/domain.c:1721, condition `mono_defaults.iunknown_class != 0' not met
07-29 14:51:34.985 E/mono-rt (13053): Stacktrace:
07-29 14:51:34.985 E/mono-rt (13053): 
07-29 14:51:34.985 E/mono-rt (13053):   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
07-29 14:51:34.985 E/mono-rt (13053):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes (System.Reflection.Assembly,bool) <IL 0x0002e, 0xffffffff>
07-29 14:51:34.985 E/mono-rt (13053):   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes () <IL 0x00002, 0x00053>
07-29 14:51:34.985 E/mono-rt (13053):   at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxTypeExtensions.ExceptionSafeGetTypes (System.Reflection.Assembly) <IL 0x00001, 0x0006b>
07-29 14:51:34.985 E/mono-rt (13053):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Platform.MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.<FindSetupType>b__8 (System.Reflection.Assembly) <IL 0x00001, 0x00043>
07-29 14:51:34.985 E/mono-rt (13053):   at System.Linq.Enumerable/<CreateSelectManyIterator>c__Iterator29`3.MoveNext () <IL 0x00066, 0x002b7>
The program 'Mono' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: I saw problems like this reported several times against Xamarin preview releases. I'd recommend checking xamarin forums or contacting Xamarin support.

Comment: I think this is a problem with linked assemblies.  If I do not skip linking other assemblies, they crash with a similar error.  But what assembly is MonoDroidConstructors??

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the following assemblies to the project properties for "Skip linking assemblies"

System.Core
System.Windows